# Loading a user's profile image

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux, firebase-storage

I am using React, Redux, and Firebase to build a website. I use firebase storage to store a user's profile image and want it to be displayed on the website once the user has created an account. My approach used to be to include the following image element in every component that needs to display the profile image:

```
//1st Approach
render(){

        const { auth } = this.props;

        return(
                       .......

                        <img src={firebase.storage().ref(`images/`+auth.uid).getDownloadURL()}></img>

                       ......
```

However, doing so displayed only the default image icon (green mountain and white cloud with sky-blue background) and the console reported the "404" error saying that the object "images/undefined" does not exist. It is likely that the error occurred because the getDownloadUrl method was called before the the auth was passed from Redux state to the component. Another approach I tried was to add a "profileimage" field in the state of the component and set the field value to the image URL inside componentDidMount:

```
//2nd Approach
        componentDidMount() {

           const { auth } = this.props;
           const id = auth.uid;
           const image = firebase.storage().ref(`images/`+id);
           image.getDownloadURL().then((url) => this.setState({ profileimage: url }));
        }

        ......

         <img src={this.state.profileimage}></img>
```

The second approach successfully displayed the image. However, since componentDidMount is only called once during the lifecycle of a component, if the user refreshes the page, the "profileimage" will be set to an empty string. So I am wondering how I can achieve the feature in the most appropriate way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The auth.uid is it the one you got from the firebase sdk ?

You can get the uid using the "onAuthStateChanged" observer :

```js
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    const image = firebase.storage().ref(`images/${user.uid}`);
    image.getDownloadURL().then((url) => this.setState({ profileimage: url }));
  });
}
```

That way, you ensure that the user is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The user is indeed initialized in my case. Using componentDidMount works but my concern is that if the user refreshes the page, then the "profileimage" will be set to an empty string again.

Comment: Every time you refresh the page, it should invoke componentDidMount again and again. Are you sure this one is not invoked ? It would be set to an empty string, but it will load it again right after from your firebase storage.

Comment: I just fixed the issue by adding componentWillReceiveProps. I'm also wondering how I can let the image be displayed immediately on the webpage once the user finishes uploading it when editing his/her profile. I later added an "image" field to my "users" firestore collection to store the unique and constant image URL of each user and set src={profile.image}. However, after uploading a different image, I need to refresh the page to see it. Fixing the issue will certainly improve user experience.

Comment: Are you using Redux ? If not, you can take a look, it lets you keep the same data on different pages, and automatically re-render your components if there is a change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I am using Redux and I know it is supposed to re-render the component if any change occurs. I am wondering whether this has to do with my keeping the profile image url constant (it is always at the page to which the firebase storage document "images/uid" belongs). So even after a user uploads a different image, the URL address is still the same and Redux "doesn't realize the change?"